# Evaluate XPath relative to context node

Tags: javascript, xpath

I am trying to evaluate an XPath relative to a particular DOM node. That is, I would like to access `/html/body/div/a` using the expression `//a`, while specifying that the XPath should be evaluated on the `<div>` element.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathEvaluator/evaluate), it seems that the `contextNode` argument should work here.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="#">outer</a>
    <div>
      <a href="#">inner</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to evaluate the XPath on the `<div>` using the `contextNode` argument, but passing it had no effect. I would have expected that now the inner `<a>` element should be found.

Instead, `document.evaluate('//a', div).iterateNext().innerText` gives the text "outer".

https://jsfiddle.net/mt04y8db/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An absolute path starting with `/` searches from the document root node (of the context node) so either use `.//a` or `descendant::a`, perhaps sufficient for your sample, simply `a`.